# lc.exe Not found in visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Sir,Im new this site ,and also for the Visual studio i install the vs2008 and, Im using xp sp3 ,when im debug my project it says

**"Task failed because "LC.exe" was not found, or the correct Microsoft Windows SDK is not installed. The task is looking for "LC.exe" in the "bin" subdirectory beneath the location specified in the InstallationFolder value of the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A. You may be able to solve the problem by doing one of the following:  1) Install the Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5.  2) Install Visual Studio 2008.  3) Manually set the above registry key to the correct location.  4) Pass the correct location into the "ToolPath" parameter of the task."**

in SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A it contains .exe called lc.exe

but in Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\SDK\v3.5\Bin there's no file or application called lc.exe

May be this is a dump question ,but plz help ..
Thanks

Comment: You posted completely garbled path names.  This is supposed to be present in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\lc.exe

Comment: Thank you sir, I exclude the licence.lcx file from the solution ,Now it's ok ,but i wont to know what is that file (licence.lcx) ?

Answer (score 0):

Task failed because "LC.exe" was not found, or the correct Microsoft Windows SDK is not installed. The task is looking for "LC.exe" in the "bin" subdirectory beneath the location specified in the InstallationFolder value of the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A. You may be able to solve the problem by doing one of the following: 1) Install the Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5. 2) Install Visual Studio 2008. 3) Manually set the above registry key to the correct location. 4) Pass the correct location into the "ToolPath" parameter of the task."